# shell script connect three commands

Tags: shell, date, time, terminal, ls

I have shell script, and need to forward number of files and folders in some directory to .txt file, I did it with ls | wc -

but in that file need to be date and time when script was ran

ls | wc -l | date > prep.txt

in file prep i have only date not this first count of files and folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date` does not read its standard input; it makes no sense to pipe into it.

```
date >prep.txt
ls | wc -l >>prep.txt
```

If you insist on a single redirection,

```
{ date; ls | wc -l; } >prep.txt
```

You could also get really complicated;

```
date +"%c $(ls | wc -l)" >prep.txt
```

but there is really no reason to go there.